# "continue" equivalent command in nested loop in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a batch file which contains nested loop with `continue`-like command:

```
for %%i in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
    for %%j in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
        if %%i gtr %%j goto CONTINUE
        test.exe 0 %%i %%j 100000 > "%%i_%%j".txt
        :CONTINUE
        rem
    )
)
```

But when `if` statement is true for the first time, it does not iterate further. I only get text files upto `1_256.txt`. So it seems that `goto CONTINUE` has a problem. What is wrong with my batch file?

Comment: In short, labels (like :CONTINUE) cannot be used inside a loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`goto :Label` inside of a block of code `()` like a `for` loop breaks the block context, so everything after the `:Label` is treated as being outside of the block. So you need to invert the `if` condition to not need `goto` as [ths's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356625) demonstrates, or you place the code fragment with `goto` and `:Label` into a subroutine and use `call` like this:

```
for %%i in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
    for %%j in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
        call :SUB %%i %%j
    )
)
exit /B

:SUB outer inner
if %1 gtr %2 goto CONTINUE
test.exe 0 %1 %2 100000 > "%1_%2.txt"
:CONTINUE
rem
exit /B
```

Answer (score 7):

it seems what you are actually trying to accomplish is a poor man's "less or equal than".
In this case, why not use the real "less or equal than", which is `LEQ`?
Additionally, you seem to want the output of test.exe in the "%%i_%%j".txt file, so don't use  `echo`.

So this would be

```
for %%i in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
    for %%j in (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) do (
        if %%i LEQ %%j test.exe 0 %%i %%j 100000 > "%%i_%%j".txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves my purpose without using any `continue`-like command. However, I assume, there is no "good" (user-friendly) `continue` equivalent thing in Windows batch scripting. I think, to accomplish such thing in complex scenario, some "dirty coding trick" is needed.